# BQ2002 NiMH Charging Circuit not working

Tags: transistors, batteries, sensor, battery-charging, charger

I have the following charging circuit based on the BQ2002 which will charge a NiMH battery using a 5V micro USB cable. I built the circuit already and noticed that the TIP32C is not getting hot and the circuit is not drawing any current, but its able to charge the battery just fine.

The circuit is supposed to turn off when the thermistor gets too hot.

Are there any major connection issues or are my resistor values wrong?

I would like to draw around 550 mA of current.

Thanks in advance

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Below is the schematic which I updated
The circuit is working now but not drawing enough current. How do I deliver more current?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5gRU.png[image]

Comment: Where does your 'VCC' supply come from? Why is your 'USB 5V Input' only connected to the circuit thru a 200k resistor?

Comment: @brhans the VCC supply comes from the 5V input, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You don't show any design specs and tolerances

Comment: How does VCC come from the 5V Input when you haven't connected them together?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 The circuit would be used to charge 2 NiMH battery and  would be charged through a 5V micro USB. I would like the current draw to be at least 550 mA and for the charging to stop when the battery pack gets too hot.

Comment: @brhans Does connecting all the 'VCC' to the +ve of the 5V input work?

Comment: "the circuit is not drawing any current, but its able to charge the battery just fine" - Free energy!!!

Comment: Your problems are mostly addressed by Jack's answer. Connecting VCC to your 5V Input will 'work' in the sense that your circuit will at least be powered, but the circuit itself is still fundamentally broken and will in all likelihood cause something to catch fire - sooner or later.

Answer (score 4):

> BQ2002 NiMH Charging Circuit not working

Thank goodness your circuit does not work. Did you read the datasheet for the [BQ2002](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2002.pdf)?

The datasheet clearly shows how to connect the controller:

[image]

1. You have no connection from Bat to the NiMH you are charging ....so no voltage sensing.
2. You have no current limiting or detection in the charge path, so no way to control the charging current.
3. You give no idea of the cell/pack voltage, but the circuit you show would only work for 1 or 2 cells since the diode drop would be close to 1V and the TIP32C saturation voltage is over 1V.

Comment: Yes, I am only charging 2 Cells. So do I just need to connect all the 'VCC' to the 5V input? to answer '2' do I just add a resistor on the charging path?

Comment: You need a solution for both 1. and 2. Look for applicable schematic on the Internet, there are many. This is barely going to work for two cells.